# can ansible-playbook read from stdin instead of a file?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible for `ansible-playbook` to read a playbook from the standard input? I thought maybe dash (-) would be a way to specify `stdin`, like it does in the `cat` command and I tried:

```sh
$ ansible-playbook -
```

But it fails with:

```
ERROR! the playbook: - could not be found
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is `/dev/stdin`, which acts like a file but, as its name implies, is the stdin of the current process.

```sh
$ ansible-playbook -i localhost, -c local /dev/stdin <<'FOO'
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="hello from stdin"
FOO
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: hello from stdin
```