# Multi-line command in ansible-console

Tags: ansible

How to enter multi-line command in [`ansible-console`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-console.html), an Ansible REPL? I'm looking for something like `\` at the end of the line in bash.

Regular writing from a playbook

```yml
- debug:
    msg: "hello"
```

can be transformed to single line form

```
$ debug msg='hello'
```

However is there a way to execute

```yml
- debug:
    msg: 'hello'
  register: result
```

in `ansible-console`?

Comment: what is the objective to register a task from a cli command?

Comment: Just to demo the problem in way that it uses pretty known options and doesn't require any special environment.

Comment: Fun fact: [ansible-playbook can run without an actual filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275015/can-ansible-playbook-read-from-stdin-instead-of-a-file/54280101#54280101) if you're just interested in a "one liner"

Answer (score 0):

Ansible ad hoc commands are for [specific use cases](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_adhoc.html), so [`ansible-console`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-console.html) as well. Therefore such things like [registering variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) aren't possible.

Whereby it would be possible [to have the output in JSON, write it into a file and try to parse it later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465035/), a small setup which doesn't require any special environment can be look like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Show message
    debug:
      msg: "Hello"
    register: message

  - name: Show registered message
    debug:
      msg: "{{ message.stdout }}"
```